# php - how to call static class and function with variable?

Tags: php, static-methods

I have tried this code with and without {} but it keeps saying "syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in .."

```
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $do = $_GET['do'];

        {$page}::{$do}();
```

Then I have a class and a function in that class that should get called which looks like this.

```
class Example {
    public static function index()
    {}
}
```

So if $page = "Example" and $do = "index" I want to call Example::index();

Comment: I should also mention that I have namespaces like \namespace\Class::function();

Comment: [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)`([$_GET["page"], $_GET["do]])` and let anyone call any arbitrary static function they want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do that:

```
//$class: the class which contains your static function
//$method: the function you want to call

call_user_func("$class::$method");
//OR
call_user_func(array($class, $method));
```

in your case:

```
call_user_func("$page::$do");
```

OR

```
call_user_func(array($page, $do));
```